# Is it true that every sufficiently large positive integer can be written as a sum of a square free number and a perfect square ?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Is it true that $\exists k \in \mathbb Z^+$ such that every integer $n >k$ can be written as a sum of a square free number and a perfect square ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. It was proved for first by Estermann, and in the following [Mirsky's article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2305811) you can find good asymptotics on the number of representations, that is obviously given by
$$ R(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}\mu^2(n-k^2).$$

Comment: Can you please  give a link to that paper of Esterman ( in english language ) or any other source ?

Comment: @SaunDev: here it is: http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-6/3/219.full.pdf+html

Comment: I have downloaded the pdf , thanks